# Display list of purchase order base from filtered vendor in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display the list of vendor with their purchase orders in a table.

VENDOR MODEL

```
public function vendorPo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PurchasedOrder', 'vendor_id','vendor_id');
}
```

VENDOR CONTROLLER

```
public function vendor()
{
    $vendorPo = Vendor::with('vendorPo')
        ->get()
        ->keyBy('id')
        ->groupBy('vendor_name');

    $purchaseOrders = PurchasedOrder::all()->where('publish','=','1');

    return view('backend.purchase-order.vendor', compact('purchaseOrders'))
            ->with('vendorPo', $vendorPo);
}
```

for my index

```
@foreach ($vendorPo as $vendor => $vendor_list)
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7"
            style="background-color: #F7F7F7"> {{ $vendor }}: ({{ $vendor_list->count() }} vendors)
        </th>
    </tr>
        @foreach ($vendor_list as $key => $vendorPoList)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $vendorPoList->vendorPo->po_id}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

if I do this

```
...
@foreach ($vendor_list as $key => $vendorPoList)
     <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $vendorPoList}}
        </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
...
```

the result is this
[image]

and if I

```
...
<td>
     {{ $vendorPoList->vendorPO->po_id}}}
</td>
...
```

the result is error

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Property [po_id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because your `vendorPO` relation is a `HasMany` relation. If you pull back the records from that sort of relation, the results are always an array (even if there is only one record), which is always converted by Eloquent into a `Collection`.

Therefore, `$vendorPoList->vendorPO` is a Collection, and there is no variable on a Collection called `po_id`.

Depending on your data model, you should either revisit the relation, or do a `@foreach` on `$vendorPoList->vendorPO`.